# Transferring text from iFRAME to a textarea using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, textarea

I'm currently working on a little html/js site and my current goal is to load a .txt file into a page (accomplished this with iFrame src), then transfer the text from the iFrame to a textArea.
The latter I cannot do for some reason. I have tried to get various scripts to help me but none of them seem to work.

Currently lets imagine i have only this in the html:

```
<iframe name=my_frame id=my_frame src=textfile.txt height=100% width=100% frameborder=0 scrolling=auto marginheight=5 marginwidth=5></iframe>
```

The java code i am using to validate whether I am getting the inner text of the iFrame is a simple alert:

```
    <script>
    alert($('my_frame').*[attribute]*);
    </script>
```

The ''attribute'' part is a dummy in this case. I've used things like HTML, innerHTML, innerTEXT, text, value, body, instead - but none of them work....

Perhaps someone here could assist with a little script to accomplish moving plain text from iFRAME to textArea, or even suggest a better way of approaching this?

I would be extremely grateful for any and all assistance.

Cpt.Mgn.

Comment: are you sure include jquery library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must change your code:

```
 <script>
    alert($('#my_frame').html());
    </script>
```

# Is a selector for id.

html() return all the html inside the element.

I hope this helps :)

EDIT:

```
<iframe name=my_frame id=my_frame src=textfile.txt height=100% width=100% frameborder=0 scrolling=auto marginheight=5 marginwidth=5>Hello </iframe>
```

And alert said: Hello

Link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/rEM6H/

Comment: I have tried this just now. Alert comes back with ''null''... :(

Comment: OK, so you are saying because i had <iframe> </iframe> the alert says null because nothing is in between the iframe tags? That would make sense but after i hard-coded the ''HELLO'' i still get a null value...

Comment: Look this link: http://jsfiddle.net/rEM6H/   . It's work. html() is for the code between the tags. val() It´s for <input type="text" value="hello"> attr() It´s a get/set for attributes of the tag.

Comment: Yes i found what was wrong... $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt1').val() = $('#my_frame').html());  
  });

Answer (score 0):

if your file is hosted and the textfile is public-ally accessible, then you can try this

```
$.get("http://yourdomain.com/a.txt", null, function(response){
    $("#theTextArea").val(response); // where theTextArea is the ID of the textarea you want to put the data into.
});
```